# try to use local storage in JS but not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend, local-storage

HTML code :

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="inp" />
    <button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
    <div class="dom">Hello</div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

JS Code :

```
const inputTxt = document.querySelector('#inp');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const dom = document.querySelector('.dom');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let txtValue = inputTxt.value;

  localStorage.setItem('inputX', txtValue);
  const storegGet = localStorage.getItem('inputX');

  dom.textContent = storegGet;
});
```

When I try to call localStorage.getItem into textContent and refresh the browser still not saved I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: You never read the store after load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure out the problem :)

```js
const inputTxt = document.querySelector('#inp');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const dom = document.querySelector('.dom');

function callBtn() {
  let txtValue = inputTxt.value;

  localStorage.setItem('inputX', txtValue);
  dom.textContent = txtValue;
  inputTxt.value = '';
}

btn.addEventListener('click', callBtn);

function getStorage() {
  if (btn) {
    dom.textContent = localStorage.getItem('inputX');
  }
}

getStorage();
```

Comment: Why `if (btn)`? `if (dom)` seems more logical given the statement that follows.

Comment: You alright , Thanks 